# XML and HTML similar tags

Tags: php, html, xml

When i use **XML tag**  in php file that contains html contents it gets confused with **html tag**  so how to differentiate between the two similar tags? thanks!

Comment: You may want to read the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help topic, as it's kind of hard to help you with your problem with no sample code demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use `<![CDATA[]]>` around the html content

[What does <![CDATA[]]> in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)

:)

If you want to show XML on page you can do

`<html><body><pre>
 <?php echo htmlentities('<?xml version="1.0"?><nodes><node>TEXT</node></nodes>');?> 
 <pre></body></html>`

But if you want show real XML in the browser do:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
print '<?xml version="1.0"?><nodes><node>TEXT</node></nodes>';
exit;
```

Maybe what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: without CDATA the HTML tag title is working as the webpage title and the XML tag title contents not showing at all but with the CDATA the XML tag title as the webpage title and the HTML tag title contents is showing as a xml tag there is my code:
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ahmed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include 'XML.php';
            
            $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
            
            echo $sxe->asXML();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: You cant post both at the same time, i update my answer